# how to make ui with different tabs and navigation drawer in one app?

Tags: android, navigation, android-viewpager, drawer

what will be the position of viewpager tag?will it be above drawer layout ? below is the code :

please reply as i am very much confused in this thing ,

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:id="@+id/myviewpager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

Comment: You need to put the `ViewPager` and the `<include>`d app bar both inside another `ViewGroup` - e.g., a vertical `LinearLayout` or a `RelativeLayout` - that would go above `NavigationView` in the `DrawerLayout`.

Comment: okay i ll try , thankyou Mike :)